# javascript: tool to detect object recursion

Tags: javascript

Yesterday I spent way too long chasing a strange bug in javascript that turned out to be caused by a circular reference in various setters. Basically setting a property of an Object runs a function; that function also caused a property to be set on another Object, which in turn ran another function, which in turn set the property again on the first Object ... ugh! Is there a way, in a build process or tool, that I can detect circular references? Here's a simplified example of a silly thing to do:

```
var a = {}, b = {};

Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", {
  get: function() {
    return b.foo;
  },
  set: function (value) {
    b.foo = value;
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(b, "foo", {
  get: function () {
    return a.foo;
  },
  set: function (value) {
    a.foo = value;
  }
});
```

Basically reading *or* writing the `foo` property of either the `a` or `b` objects causes an infinite loop.

Comment: [No](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Oh yes. Fair enough!

Comment: @Bergi: Detecting a loop ≠ halting problem. It is [very much solvable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).

Comment: @9000 The state space of js programs is not finite, cycle detection doesn't apply there. Of course we can detect *some* loops, but not all of them.

Comment: @Bergi: The question above reads: «Is there a way, in a build process or tool, that I can detect circular references?» Loop detection works, as it would in finite state space, because we normally assume that the structure where we are looking for the loop is not mutating, and is physically finite. Else the notion of a cycle becomes ill-defined.

Comment: @9000 The problem is that JavaScript is too dynamic. Even if you could fit a particular code in a statically typed model, I don't see why you would assume that the structure is not mutating or consist of a finite number of objects. Which structure do you think of, the class diagram? Sure, you could detect circular dependencies in there, but I'd call that [graph cycle detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)#Cycle_detection) not function cycle detection. And while it would be able to detect things like (mutually) recursive calls, it still couldn't say whether they halt.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not the answer since you asked for a tool, I did not find any such tool except trying to see the call stack.

However, I could avoid the infinite recursion in many ways, I can add conditionals that the function should return if a condition is met. That's how we deal with recursive functions.

For example, one of them is to use a counter or another variable or property and make sure the function will return data only once,

```
var a = {}, b = {};
var callCounter = 0;

Object.defineProperty(a, "foo", {
  get: function() {
    if(++callCounter < 2){
      console.log("Getting value from some other object since I don't have it.")
      return b.foo;
    }else{
      console.log("Why was I called again? :/");
      callCounter = 0;
      return null;
    }
  },
  set: function (value) {
    b.foo = value;
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(b, "foo", {
  get: function () {
      return a.foo;
  },
  set: function (value) {
    a.foo = value;
  }
});

console.log(a.foo)
```